# replacing window.showmodaldialog with window.open

Tags: javascript

In Many application, many of popups are implemented using window.showmodaldialog which restricts user to finish work on popup before changing focus to any other aprt of application. I want to change the implementation from modal dialog (window.showmodaldialog) to independent window (window.open).  could you please help me with steps which has to be followed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple `window.open([URL], 'width=[some number],height=[some number]');`.

In this if you have any return values with `window.showmodaldialog` which you are using in the opener window, you have to handle them with `window.opener`.

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open <s>http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp</s>

Comment: A better reference is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)