# Difference between window instances, JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm calling `var xyz = window.showModalDialog(//parameters)` from the parent window.
Now at the when the new window is open, on a click event I'm supposed to return a value so I'm using this right now:

```
window.returnValue = someReturnValue;
```

Although I was not getting the value in the window.returnValue on the parent page.
So I tried using these:

```
window.returnValue = someReturnValue;
parent.window.returnValue = someReturnValue;
window.parent.returnValue = someReturnValue;
```

I can see a property `window.parent` under watch over the object `window`

Now, I tried putting a different value in the each of the above, and the console displayed the value as I had assigned. Hence they are defiantly different. As of the parent itself seems to content all the properties including returnValue.

If I have to access the value in the parent window am I using this right?

```
//At the parent side
var xyz = window.showModalDialog(//parameters)

//in the new Window
window.returnValue = someReturnValue;
```

Comment: Are you seeing a problem or asking for code review ? `window.returnValue` is a perfectly valid use in this case.

Comment: It's worth noting that `window.showModalDialog()` is deprecated and no longer supported in chrome. You shouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: More of a code review @Pogrindis, Because I'm getting this weird behavior the in IE 11 standard mode as I'm not getting the value of `window.showModalDialog()` at the parent. Same code seems to work fine on any else version.

Comment: I would follow the suggestion of @MadaraUchiha here, and use an alternative method for `showModalDialog()` // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622395/replacing-window-showmodaldialog-with-window-open IE: `Window.open()` possibly using javascript's `localStorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage to transfer between windows.

Comment: I was keen to solve this with `showModalDialog()` itself, but after this weird behavior, I tried it with a Callback function as an arguments and stored the value as `parent.parent.mySource.MyCallback(someReturnValue)` in the new window. Now I'm getting the value from the variable declared at the parent and assigned in the Callback function. 
But still wondering what's wrong with the `window.returnValue`.
Thanks for the help @Pogrindis :)