# showModalDialog() opens a new browser windown on IE but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, showmodaldialog

When I submit a form using `showModalDialog()`.It submit to Struts2 Action.After executing business logic it shows the response on new Browser window  Instead of same window on IE.

Its working fine using `window.open()`.

Any lead will appreciate

Answer (score 3):

In https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog says:

Deprecated:
This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

Here more documentation about showModalDialog() alternative:

[replacing window.showmodaldialog with window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622395/replacing-window-showmodaldialog-with-window-open)

Comment: Thanks sir but when I uses window.open() it shows maximize minimize but.which a ModalDialog dont have'

Comment: Don't use deprecated features. Change your mind and use the best things you can now